# Infinite rollback - SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server, ssms, rollback

I have a strange situation. An script (dele from ...) was running at SQL Managment Studio in a VM machine but this machine died on the night, the process apparently was not affected but I did the kill to start the process again.

Now I have a infinite rollback, today the rollback complete 1 week, my feelings said to not restart the service and wait forever. I want to stop de rollback even with data loss in the table.

[image: infinete rollback]

Someone Know how can I stop the rollback?

Comment: Check if the cpu_time, reads, writes or logical_reads are increasing or are static for that session. It's likely that's a doomed transaction which will never end and will only be removed when restarting the service. This happens when the connection uses external tools (like CMD prompt) and is unexpectedly shut down.

Comment: I've seen what @EzLo said. Those transactions will disappear after a service restart. More info - https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2015/08/31/sql-server-spid-is-killedrollback-state-what-to-do-next/

Comment: Tks for answer. Apparently the rollback is running because the log until yesterday was incresing a lot. (>1.2 Tb). If I run the select on sys.sysprocesses I can see that the CPU and Physical_io is changing...

Comment: just to update, the rollback was finished with 210 hours!